# Rewrite condition in .htaccess for slash and non slash version throws status code 500

Tags: apache, .htaccess, server, redirect

We are trying to set up a redirection rule in .htaccess so our every URL with slash in the end is redirected to a non slash version.

We have implemented this code which i believe should do the work:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301] 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

What is happening now is, when I try to visit the slash version, I get 500 status code. Here is the URL of the website: plicnivek.cz. Is our .htaccess rule implemented correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Your rule  is incorrect as it also rewrites non-existent files directory  to PHP. You can use the following rule to remove trailing slash and  rewrite php extension.

```
RewriteEngine on


#remove traling slash 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.*)/$ /$1 [R=301,L]
#remove .php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule (.+)/?$ /$1.php [L]
```

Comment: We have implemented your rule and It still returns 500 - see plicnivek.cz/clanky/ @starkeen

Comment: @TomasNosek Can you please check your error log file?